# Rails app datetime search using Ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ransack

I was about to implement a search function where users can filter a datetime column. 
I am currently using rails `datetime_field_tag` however I can't seem to make it work with ransack where people can choose a date with time in hours and minutes then either AM or PM.

Users can enter datetime in this format: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM` 
 
The column that i am searching for is in datetime format, ex: `2021-05-12 09:09:48`

What's the best way to implement this one? with ransack or not? and how? 
just my first time implementing datetime search function with ransack,

I tried searching online but i cant seem to find a good solution.
thanks.

Comment: Do u have to have  AM/PM? Seems like 09 vs 21 should be enough no? And please share your relevant code and specify where things don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're receiving the datetime in string format from parameters and directly passing it to ransack, then you should convert that string to 24-hour format string (db format can also be used) first and then pass it to ransack.

For example

```rb
query_value = Time.zone.parse(params[:created_at_filter]).to_s(:db)
Person.ransack(created_at_eq: query_value)
```