Rails 6 active record time zone search issues
My rails 6.0.3 application works on a postgres database and it has an order_datetime column(timestamp without time zone) and Configured time_zone to Kolkata in application.rb. It is +5.30 hours ahead of UTC

config.time_zone = 'Kolkatta'

When user submitting the current datetime(2024-08-12 01:42:02 AM) for parameter of order_datetime, the value will be stored as previous date in the database column like 2024-08-11 20:12:02. But will show the actual value 2024-08-12 01:42 AM when retrieving by app(l object.order_datetime).
No problem so far.
Problems start with searching by date. When user searches by current date 2024-08-12, no result is generated on this date because the value in database is stored in an earlier date. I'm using ransack gem for simple search.
sales_controller.rb
def index
  @search = Sale.ransack(params[:q])
end

sale.rb model
order_datetime_eq do
  Arel.sql("date(order_datetime)")
end

index.html.haml
= search_form_for @search, url: sales_path, method: :get do |search|
= search.search_field :order_datetime_eq, value: (l Date.current), :class => "form-control"

# Here Date.current returns current date as 2024-08-12 01:42 AM


think you might  need to give ransack a little help -- take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631320/rails-app-datetime-search-using-ransack-gem

The problem is you are losing information that the database needs to handle the timezone conversion properly. Your converting to a DATE() and your records are in the DB in the previous day, so this won't work.
What you want is a range query with a datetime that covers the day in question, and will get converted to the proper range.
This basic rails range query would work.
where(order_datetime: Date.current.midnight..(Date.current.midnight + 1.day))
With this the two ends of the range will get shifted to UTC when the query is run against the database.
You should be able to rewrite your ransacker to use that range query rather than a DATE cast and it will preserve your timezone conversion.
